# Which set includes a large white mask

Tags: piece-information, hero-factory

I bought a sealed bag at Goodwill but It did not include any information on what set it is from.

Pieces look like large white body plates, skeletal/Stormtrooper mask and tusks.

[image: Skeleton-type head]

[image: White body parts]

Answer (score 2):

The mask in the first picture is from the Hero Factory set [Witch Doctor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=2283-1#T=I).
The other pic looks like it's from the same set.